# How to Update the Data Base based on the sensor output?

Tags: android, oracle10g, sensors, android-sensors

I have to create an Android App for Automated Parking System. Let me give you the overall background idea of this app development.

I should be able to find out in which floor where parking place is available when I was entering in to my office, through my mobile phone Antroid App.

The parking place availability information should be automatically gets updated in my database where my Android App is going to hit through webservice.

Lets assume like I am going to keep a sensor infront of the each parking place. So when a person parking his car then the sensor will be active. So by this time in my DB one new data should be entered.

When the person taking away his car from that parking place, my sensor will be on nonactive state. So at this time that respective data should gets deleted from my DB.

So basically I want to know can we makes this DB updation based on the sensor output? If so how could we achive?

Please let me know if you have any questions on understanding my req.

Looking forward for your quick responses. Thanks!

Regards,
Velava.S

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to connect the sensors to a central server which would monitor the status of each sensor.  Dependant on how the sensors worked they would either send a signal when there state changed, at fixed time intervals, or the server would have to poll input.
Once a change has been sent/recieved by the server it would update a database of all sensor states.

When your app then makes requests to this server it would respond with a formatted XML response on the availability of each floor.

I'm afraid I can't give exact details on how to connect the sensor array, most likely for this type of project it would be a custom built box, if you search around you should find some suppliers, or if you are just learning you can have a look at http://www.arduino.cc/ - these are programmable microcontrollers so you could build a prototype with them.

Comment: Thanks for your response paul!

Comment: Could you please explain more on how exactly we can connect the server with sensor device?

Comment: Eh wait, in what way does it concern android sensors ?

Comment: @Greg-bfG No part of this currect specification would directly involve Android sensors.